# ID got null in json (id=null) RESTapi Python flask sqlite. What to do if id is equal to null

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, primary-key, create-table

Using flask framework I created table in SQLite with 3 rows `(id, author, title)`. While i run program `id` is equal to `null` `(id=null)` in `JSON` format. Please help out to this.
I created 2 files in python `app.py` to run my code in flask framework and `db.py` to create a database in SQLite
`app.py flie`

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import sqlite3
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

def db_connection():
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('books.sqlite')
    except sqlite3.error as e:
        print(e)
    return conn

@app.route('/books', methods=['GET','POST'])
def books():
    conn = db_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    if request.method == 'GET':
        cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
        books = [
            dict(id=row[0],author=row[1], title=row[2])
            for row in cursor.fetchall()
        ]
        if books is not None:
            return jsonify(books)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_author = request.form['author']
        new_title = request.form['title']
        sql = """
                INSERT INTO books (author,title) VALUES (?,?)
        """
        cursor = cursor.execute(sql, (new_author,new_title))
        conn.commit()

        return f'Book with the id: {cursor.lastrowid} created successfully',201
```

`db.py flie`

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("books.sqlite")

cursor = conn.cursor()

sql_query = """ 
    CREATE TABLE books (
        id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMERY KEY,
        author varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        title varchar(255) NOt NULL
    )
    """

cursor.execute(sql_query)
```

Comment: `PRIMERY KEY` should be `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: just fyi, `select *` with indexed access (`row[0]` etc) is a terrible idea; use named column references or an explicit column list in the select statement instead

Comment: `PRIMERY KEY` should be `PRIMARY KEY`. maybe sqlite silently ignores it otherwise and doesn't apply auto increment if it's not actually a PK?

Comment: I solve the correction of `PRIMARY KEY`. I delete database and create it again. but still `id=null`. i shared [link](my https://github.com/TejasMankarr/Books-Library) link also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    author TEXT NOT NULL,
    title TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Notice that you should define the column `id` as `INTEGER` and not `int`, if you want the column to be autoincremented.
The keyword [`AUTOINCREMENT`](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) (and not `AUTO_INCREMENT`) is optional and you should use it only if you don't want deleted id values to be reused in new rows.
Also, there is no `VARCHAR` [data type in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Use `TEXT`.

Comment: Yes, Thank  you for this correction.

Comment: @TejasMankar this is not a correction. It is a solution. Did you change int to INTEGER?

Comment: Yes @forpas now `id` is not `null`